# How to use a reference in a trigger?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, reference, oracle9i

I have a problem with `triggers`. First of all, I have this:

The types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_Lineaventa AS OBJECT
(id NUMBER(5),
 cantidad NUMBER(5),
 precio_venta NUMBER(5,2),
 refProducto REF Tipo_Producto);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tipo_Producto AS OBJECT
(codigo NUMBER(5),
 modelo VARCHAR(15),
 precio NUMBER(5,2),
 stock_disp NUMBER(3),
 esSuministrado Tipo_esSuministrado
) NOT FINAL;
/
```

And the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla_Lineaventa OF Tipo_Lineaventa
( CONSTRAINT PK_Tabla_Lineaventa PRIMARY KEY (id),
refProducto NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Tabla_Producto OF Tipo_Producto
( CONSTRAINT PK_Tabla_Producto PRIMARY KEY (codigo),
  CONSTRAINT AK_Tabla_Producto UNIQUE(modelo))
NESTED TABLE esSuministrado STORE AS NT_esSuministrado;
```

And now, I have this `trigger`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkQuantity
BEFORE INSERT ON Tabla_Lineaventa
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    stock Tabla_Producto.stock_disp%TYPE;
    cod Tabla_Producto.codigo%TYPE;
    aux Tipo_Producto;

BEGIN
    SELECT DEREF(:OLD.refProducto).codigo INTO cod FROM dual;

    SELECT stock_disp INTO stock FROM Tabla_Producto P WHERE P.codigo = cod;

    IF stock > :OLD.cantidad THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK')
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
    END IF;
END checkQuantity;
/
```

With the sentence `SELECT DEREF(:OLD.refProducto).codigo INTO cod FROM dual;` I have problem, because not return my product `codigo` attribute that I'm referencing in `refProducto`.

How can I solve it? I need to know if I have enought stock for do a new 'Lineaventa'.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is *the* issue, but at the very least, for a [`BEFORE INSERT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#sthref7907) trigger, `OLD:` is *null*. You should use the `NEW:` pseudorecord to access the post-insert value.

```
    SELECT DEREF(:OLD.refProducto).codigo INTO cod FROM dual;
--               ^^^^
--               here

...

    IF stock > :OLD.cantidad THEN
--             ^^^^
--           and here
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#sthref784